# How to do per-pixel destruction in Unity?

Tags: unity, physics, pixel

I want to make a game like Liero or Worms but with physics.

I have no Knowledge of code, and I searched all over the Internet and all I found were either 3D Voxel Destruction, or 2D Tile map Destruction.

The thing I'm searching for is a Multiplayer splitscreen Realtime shooting game with pixel physics destruction game.

Comment: "I have no Knowledge of code" then you're probably a bit too early in your learning journey to attempt a game like this. Start simpler, and work your way up. I don't think a single answer post here could give you all the knowledge you need to get from no code knowledge to creating a physics-based game with per-pixel destruction. You'll need to make your way there in smaller steps.

Comment: Once you have some solid coding skills in Unity, [implementing something like this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158906/39518) would be reasonably straightforward. But you'll need to deeply understand those fundamentals first, and there's no shortcut for that.